# Add location dynamically in Amazon Redshift create table statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create external table in Amazon Redshift using statement
mentioned at [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html#:%7E:text=To%20view%20external%20tables%2C%20query,Parquet%20or%20delimited%20text%20format.).

In my case I want location To be parameterized instead of static value

I am using dB Weaver for Amazon redshift

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Where do you want to get the location? You just want a function where you can specify what to create and where?

Answer (score 0):

If your partitions are hive compatible(`<partition_column_name>=<partition_column_value>`) and your table is defined via Glue or Athena, then you can run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` on the Athena table directly, which would add them. Read this thread for more info: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=800945

You can also try using [partition projections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html), if you don't use hive compatible partitions, where you define the structure of the files location in relation to the partitions and parameters.

If those don't work with you, you can use AWS Glue Crawlers which supposedly automatically detect partitions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html

If that doesn't work for you, well then your problem is very specific. I suggest pulling up your sleeves and write some code, deploy on Lambda or AWS Glue Python Shell Job. Here's a bunch of examples where other people tried that:

- https://medium.com/swlh/add-newly-created-partitions-programmatically-into-aws-athena-schema-d773722a228e
- https://medium.com/@alsmola/partitioning-cloudtrail-logs-in-athena-29add93ee070